# Please help with $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{N}\frac{2r+3}{3^r(r+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find $$ \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{2r+3}{3^r (r+1)} $$

I don't understand how to split this fraction into partial fractions which I need to do to complete the rest of the question

Comment: Split it into $2\sum \frac 1 {3^{r}}+\sum \frac 1 {3^{r}(r+1)}$.

Comment: Why do you do it this way

Comment: The given sum is made up of geometric sums as suggested by the factor $3^{r}$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You cannot really split it into partial fractions, since it is not a rational function. However, you can rewrite it as
$$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2r+2+1}{3^r(r+1)}=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2}{3^r}+\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{(r+1)3^r}=2\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{3^r}+3\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{(r+1)3^{r+1}}$$
The first sum is the sum of consecutive terms of a geometric series. As to the second sum, you may use that
$$\biggl(\frac 1{(r+1)x^{r+1}}\biggr)'= -\frac 1{x^{r+2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
$$
\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2r+3}{3^r(r+1)} =\\ 
\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{2r + 2 + 1}{3^{r}(r+1)} = \\
\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{2r + 2}{3^{r}(r+1)} + \sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3^{r}(r+1)}
$$

Now you might handle them separately:
$$
\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{2r + 2}{3^{r}(r+1)} = 2\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{3^r}
$$
Second one:
$$
\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3^{r}(r+1)}
$$